# PCI-DSS: Virtualization segmentation in ESXi environment

Tags: security, virtualization, vmware-esxi, pci-dss

I have already asked this question over on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73121/pci-dss-recomendations-for-mixed-mode-virtual-environments) but so far it has not garnered any comments. I am thinking perhaps it is more of a server infrastructure and configuration question, rather than a security question per se.

Therefore I will try to be brief:

We are PCI-DSS 2.0 compliant. PCI-DSS has the concept of in-scope and out-of-scope systems/processes/data/infrastructure etc. In-scope is under scrutiny during PCI-DSS audits, out-of-scope are considered untrusted and firewalled network segments should separate the two scopes.

Therefore it is considered a no-no if you try to mix in-scope and out-of-scope systems yet in this world of VMs the PCI-DSS council released guidelines specifically regarding mixing scopes in the virtual environment. They state that:

> *The level of segmentation required for in-scope and out-of-scope
>   systems on the same host must be equivalent to a level of isolation
>   achievable in the physical world; that is, segmentation must ensure
>   that out-of-scope workloads or components cannot be used to access an
>   in-scope component. Unlike separate physical systems, network-based
>   segmentation alone cannot isolate in-scope from out-of-scope
>   components in a virtual environment.*

Therefore my question is, **is it possible to segment VMs running on ESXi 5.5 such that the segmentation satisfies the criteria outlined in the guidelines above?**

The guidlines are very prescriptive, indeed they go on to say:

> *Segmentation of virtual components must also be applied to all virtual
>   communication mechanisms, including the hypervisor and underlying
>   host, as well as any other common or shared component. In virtual
>   environments, out-of-band communications can occur, often via a
>   solution-specific communication mechanism, or through the use of
>   shared resources such as file systems, processors, volatile and
>   non-volatile memory, device drivers, hardware devices, APIs, and so
>   on.*

Methods I have thought of:

- Use different physical network adapters
- Use different physical datastores

But other areas I am stuck on include how to segment processors, RAM etc.

If you are interested the complete PCI-DSS virtualisation guidelines are [here](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/Virtualization_InfoSupp_v2.pdf).

Thanks for reading.

**Update 21/11/2014:**
This doc [here](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/Coalfire-PCI-DSS-Compliance-and-VMware-WP.pdf) has been passed on to me, I will read and digest. It looks like a useful title: 'PCI-DSS Compliance and VMWare'.

Comment: Was my information useful to you?

Comment: Yes it was, don't worry I hadn't forgotten you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also seen the [document you linked](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/Coalfire-PCI-DSS-Compliance-and-VMware-WP.pdf) in your question. Unfortunately, it breaks down when VMware starts to push their vCloud design and security modules.

Can you tell us about *your* vSphere environment? Specifically, I'd like to understand the license tier and high level design of your vSphere infrastructure (*e.g. 3-host cluster running vSphere Essentials Plus and an iSCSI SAN*) This information will help guide to the right solution.

Generically, I can say:

- VLANs aren't enough for network segmentation. If you're trunking ports back to a switch, you really want to trunk that to a VLAN-aware firewall. You'll need firewalling between the vSphere portgroups/VLANs.
- This can be accomplish with vSphere's firewalling product, depending on your license.
- vSwitch uplinks can be linked to discrete network zones or controlled with a firewall as above.
- The datastores can be separate, but don't necessarily need separate hardware. Multiple LUNs or NFS mounts have been satisfactory in my experience.
- How are you handling physical security?
- Is your vCenter linked to Active Directory? Can you apply two-factor authentication to your AD logons?
- The ESXi hypervisor has not been a problem in audits. Make sure you have vSphere Update Manager and an established patching schedule to deal with the fixes for CVE vulnerabilities.
- If you need to guarantee a certain type of performance or certain RAM/CPU allocations, you can establish vSphere Resource Pools.
- Further separation can leverage vSphere DRS and affinity/anti-affinity rules, if your license supports it (*e.g. make sure production DB is always on a different host than development DB* or *always keep these components of the application stack together*).